# Search box rendering bug on SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, rendering

I'm seeing the search box try to render in a different spot than normal on Stack Overflow in Firefox.

[image: SO search bar]

As you can see, the text field is also half cut off by the enclosing div.  Is anyone else seeing this?  (It's displaying normally here on meta.)

Comment: No, but your top bar has more links than mine.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: That's a good point, but I have the same set of links here on meta.

Comment: Right now, the version numbers in the bottom right corner are different between Meta and SO (with SO < Meta). I assume some kind of update would be coming soon to SO.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Ah, sharp eye.  The api dev site (rendering normally) is at an even later revision. I'll wait and see what happens.

Comment: @Bill You have more badges on SO though.

Comment: This started happening for me yesterday or today... and my nav bar doesn't have any extra links. Happy that Jeff has fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**: Remove the `max-width:750px` from `#topbar` in the `all.css` file.

---

Bill, I have the same exact problem. The search box is 200px wide, if I remember correctly. Making it smaller, ~125px, will move it back up on the top row. With our names being so long ("Jonathan Sampson" and "Bill the Lizard") it creates less horizontal space. Include the additional moderator link, and badge-counts in the triple digits - you start to lose horizontal space quickly.

I've been living with this problem for months now - you kinda get comfortably numb to it ;)

Comment: I'm kinda shocked you didn't write a GreaseMonkey script to fix it. :)

Comment: @Jon I did, but then I started browsing in Chrome primarily. I could write a user-script for Chrome, but as I said, I'm **comfortably** numb ;)

Comment: I'll bet this is it.

Comment: I guess I have to keep the moderator queue cleared if I want to search. :)

Comment: Not even that fixes it for me - I may wind up writing a user script to resize it.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see -- thanks Jonathan, this was inconsistently implemented in the CSS across the Trilogy.

I removed the width everywhere it was in place.

Comment: Vista Home Premium.  Clearing the cache didn't help.

Comment: Did you try having a long name Jeff? Bill and Jonathan have longer names than you.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I appreciate how quickly you get this stuff done - keep up the great work, man.

Answer (score 0):

I saw it for a bit as well, but it's gone now. It disappeared at the same time that the search box font differences between SO, SF, SU, and MSO went away, so probably someone poking the templates.